# Can Cisco wlan-controllers (nm-air-wlc6) function like a regular fast-ethernet port?

Tags: cisco, wlan

I have a Cisco router at school that has a wlan-controller.I connected a wlan-controller to another fast-ethernet port on another router and  configured ip addresses. Although they are directly connected they are not able to ping each other.

I want to know if you can configure it to work as a regular ethernet port.

Answer (score 0):

As per http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_4/12_4x/12_4xa/boxernm.html , the FE port is not supported, so, no.